# Adding plots to a list ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am trying to add ggplot2 plots to a list so that I can use the ggarrange function from ggpubr to organise them over several pages.

As there are several hundred plots I am using a function to generate and save the plots, but I can't get it to return the plots to the environment or write the names to a list.

I'm fairly certain it's something simple that I am missing but can't spot it.

The plotting function that I am using is:

```
histFacet.plot <- function(x, results, info, ...) {

  md<- names(x) %in% c("rn","Taxa","year","rep","block","column",
                       "range", "entity_id")
  traits <- names(x[ , !md])
  for (i in traits) {
    i <-ggplot(data = x, aes_string(x = i)) + 
      geom_histogram(colour="black", fill="white") + 
      #facet_grid(x$year ~ .) +
      theme_bw() +
      xlab(paste0(i)) +
      ylab("Frequency") +
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
      theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
      theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 15)) +
      theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 15)) +
      theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 15)) 
    #ggsave(paste0(i,"_",info,".pdf"),path=paste(results, sep=''))
    plotList<- list(plotList, list(i))
    print(i)

  }
  return(i)
}

histFacet.plot(pd,'~/Dropbox/Research_Poland_Lab/AM Panel/Figures/Hist/',
               "_raw_2018")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your big problem is that you `return(i)` instead of `return(plotList)`. Re-assigning `i` inside the `for` loop using `i` as in iterator is weird. Especially when the plot uses `i` as a string... I'd try this:

```
histFacet.plot <- function(x, results, info, ...) {

  md <- names(x) %in% c("rn","Taxa","year","rep","block","column",
                       "range", "entity_id")
  traits <- names(x[ , !md])
    plotList = list()
    for (i in traits) {
        thisPlot <- ggplot(data = x, aes_string(x = i)) + 
          geom_histogram(colour="black", fill="white") + 
          #facet_grid(x$year ~ .) +
          theme_bw() +
          xlab(i) +
          ylab("Frequency") +
          theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
          theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
          theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 15)) +
          theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 15)) +
          theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 15)) 

        plotList[[i]] = thisPlot
        print(i)

      }
      return(plotList)
}
```

Untested, of course, since you didn't share sample data. Happy to test/debug if you provide a small, reproducible example data set.

I'm not really sure if you want `print(i)` to print the plot to the graphics device (if so, change to `print(thisPlot)`) or to print the current trait to the console to update progress through the loop (if so, change to `message(i)` to make it easy to disable).

A couple other notes: if you facet, use `year ~ .` as the formula, not `x$year ~ .`. If `i` is already a chracter, then `paste0(i)` is the same as `i` (in your `xlab`).

Comment: Sorry I know better than to post before checking. Here is a link to the data https://www.dropbox.com/s/4fdrrnkd4qb0oh2/Pheno_18.txt?dl=0

Comment: This solution prints the plotList to the console but does not save it or save the plots in the environment so that they can be called in ggarrange.

Comment: You have to assign the result of a function to store it. Just like if you have `x <- 1:5`, running `mean(x)` doesn't create a variable in your environment with the result unless you assign it, `mean_x <- mean(x)`. You need to assign the result of this function too, `my_list_of_plots <- histFacet.plot(...)`, then `my_list_of_plots` will be a list of the plots that you can use with `ggarrange` or whatever.

Comment: Thank you. That really would never have occurred to me without a lot more tea